# I have a function but Iwant to understand what the following lines of code are doing

Tags: python, function, dataframe, dictionary, data-science

I got a json file from an api request and I used json_normalize to convert it to a dataframe.
One of the columns, namely "venue.categories" contains a list of dictionaries. It looks like this:

```
nearby_venues.loc[0,'venue.categories']

    [{'id': '4bf58dd8d48988d16a941735',
  'name': 'Bakery',
  'pluralName': 'Bakeries',
  'shortName': 'Bakery',
  'icon': {'prefix': 'https://ss3.4sqi.net/img/categories_v2/food/bakery_',
   'suffix': '.png'},
  'primary': True}]
```

I want a new column with only the shortname i.e 'Bakery' as a column value.
The below function does the job. I need to understand what's happening under the hood.

```
def get_category_type(row):
    try:
        categories_list = row['categories']
    except:
        categories_list = row['venue.categories']

    if len(categories_list) == 0:
        return None
    else:
        return categories_list[0]['name']
```

Comment: What exactly is confusing about it? And if you don't understand it, where did it come from?

Answer (score 0):

The first block of code:

```
    try:
        categories_list = row['categories']
    except:
        categories_list = row['venue.categories']
```

is doing a copy of the column `categories`, and if fail of `venue.categories` into the variable `categories_list`.

The second block:

```
    if len(categories_list) == 0:
        return None
    else:
        return categories_list[0]['name']
```

return `None`, if the column a no data, else returns the first element of the list (there is only one) and then returns the value `key` inside the dictionnary.